# Empty files on S3 prevent from downloading using s3cmd and s3sync

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to setup a backup/restore using S3. The upload sync worked well using s3sync. However, next to each folder there is an empty file with matching name. I read somewhere that this is created to define the folder structure but I am not sure about that as it doesn't happen if I create a folder using a different method s3fox etc.

These empty files prevent me from restoring the directories/files. When I do s3cmd sync, I get an error message "can not make directory: File exists" as it first creates that empty file and that fails when trying to create the directory. Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @ThomasLevine no, I quit trying shortly after and took a different approach for the backup need

Comment: Heh neither did I. I think I deleted the empty files and reviewed my download and hoped that it was right. Fortunately this won't be an issue in the future, as I'm moving my backups to an old fashioned standard filesystem.